# Could not find an available JavaScript runtime (Telegram bot on Python & Heroku)

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my tiny bot for Telegram on Heroku. Unfortunately it doesn't work. This is what I see in my "heroku logs":

```
2022-06-19T13:51:08.829364+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py`
2022-06-19T13:51:09.412655+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-06-19T13:51:10.244258+00:00 app[worker.1]: Using United States server backend.
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696067+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2022-06-19 13:51:18,695 (util.py:66 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "RuntimeUnavailableError occurred, args=('Could not find an available JavaScript runtime.',)
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696089+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696091+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 60, in run
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696091+00:00 app[worker.1]: task(*args, **kwargs)
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696092+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 40, in send_welcome
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696092+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = ts.bing(result, from_language='ru', to_language='en')
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696093+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/translators/apis.py", line 902, in bing_api
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696093+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.tk = self.get_tk(host_html)
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696093+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/translators/apis.py", line 856, in get_tk
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696094+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = execjs.get().eval(result_str)
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696094+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/execjs/_runtimes.py", line 21, in get
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696095+00:00 app[worker.1]: return get_from_environment() or _find_available_runtime()
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696095+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/execjs/_runtimes.py", line 49, in _find_available_runtime
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696096+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise exceptions.RuntimeUnavailableError("Could not find an available JavaScript runtime.")
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696096+00:00 app[worker.1]: execjs._exceptions.RuntimeUnavailableError: Could not find an available JavaScript runtime.
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696096+00:00 app[worker.1]: "
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696210+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696225+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 56, in <module>
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696380+00:00 app[worker.1]: bot.polling()
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696388+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 392, in polling
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696519+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696527+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 416, in __threaded_polling
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696645+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696647+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 109, in raise_exceptions
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696727+00:00 app[worker.1]: six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696735+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696932+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise value
2022-06-19T13:51:18.696942+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 60, in run
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697016+00:00 app[worker.1]: task(*args, **kwargs)
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697025+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 40, in send_welcome
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697097+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = ts.bing(result, from_language='ru', to_language='en')
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697105+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/translators/apis.py", line 902, in bing_api
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697410+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.tk = self.get_tk(host_html)
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697411+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/translators/apis.py", line 856, in get_tk
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697715+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = execjs.get().eval(result_str)
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697724+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/execjs/_runtimes.py", line 21, in get
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697798+00:00 app[worker.1]: return get_from_environment() or _find_available_runtime()
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697806+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/execjs/_runtimes.py", line 49, in _find_available_runtime
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697872+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise exceptions.RuntimeUnavailableError("Could not find an available JavaScript runtime.")
2022-06-19T13:51:18.697904+00:00 app[worker.1]: execjs._exceptions.RuntimeUnavailableError: Could not find an available JavaScript runtime.
2022-06-19T13:51:18.900263+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-19T13:51:19.187322+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I was thinking that the problem might have been with pyexecjs or nodejs, so I added it into requirements.txt:

```
PyTelegramBotAPI==3.6.7
telebot==0.0.4
translators==5.2.2
numpy==1.22.4
pyexecjs
nodejs
```

Changing python versions etc is of no effect as well.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when deploying my vercel serverless function.

PyExecJS has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.

> This library is no longer maintananced (Reason). Bugs are not be fixed (even if they are trivial or essential).We suggest to use other library or to make a fork.

Try [Js2Py](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/)

> Translates JavaScript to Python code. Js2Py is able to translate and execute virtually any JavaScript code. Js2Py is written in pure python and does not have any dependencies. Basically an implementation of JavaScript core in pure python.

```py
js = execjs.compile(func_ub9)
res = js.call('ub98484234')
```

```py
context = js2py.EvalJs()
context.execute(func_ub9)
res = context.ub98484234()
```